# C - faster locking of integer when using PThreads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, io, pthreads

I have a counter that's used by multiple threads to write to a specific element in an array. Here's what I have so far...

```
int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

void *Foo()
{
    // something = random value from I/O redirection
    pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    count = count + 1;
    currentCount = count;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    // do quick assignment operation. array[currentCount] = something
}
main()
{
    // create n pthreads with the task Foo
}
```

The problem is that it is ungodly slow. I'm accepting a file of integers as I/O redirection and writing them into an array. It seems like each thread spends a lot of time waiting for the lock to be removed. Is there a faster way to increment the counter?

Note: I need to keep the numbers in order which is why I have to use a counter vs giving each thread a specific chunk of the array to write to.

Comment: If I understand you: You have a pipe full of integers, and you're reading from the pipe and writing the integers to an array. Why do we need threads here?

Comment: I was thinking you could use `sem_post` as an atomic counter, but unfortunately you can't atomically read the old/new value of the semaphore as part of the post operation.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interlocking.  Check out the [Interlocked*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function on windows, or apple's [OSAtomic*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/atomic.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/atomic) functions, or maybe [libatomic](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libatomic-ops-dev) on linux.

If you have a compiler that supports C++11 well you may even be able to use [std::atomic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a00371.html).

Comment: I thought about atomics, but I'm not sure they solve the problem. They make a _single_ operation atomic, such as `x++` but this question has _two_ operations: `x++` and `y = x`. There's a possibility of a thread switch between those two which would result in both threads writing to the same array index.

Comment: since currentCount is local, `currentCount = ++count` where `++count` is atomic would be perfect...

Comment: @paxdiablo it is possible to change 2 values if CPU has CAS2 kind of instruction.

Comment: @toby, don't make the mistake of thinking atomicity works at the level of C statements :-) Even if `count++` were atomic the assignment of the value to `currentCount` is _not_ part of the same atom. In other words, `count` could be incremented _again_ (by another thread) before the assignment.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm well aware of this. I'm suggesting an atomic increment function which returns the value incremented to (as `++` does). My phrasing was somewhat ambiguous - perhaps "where ++ is atomic" should have been "if ++ were atomic".

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option is to batch up the changes locally somewhere before applying the batch to your protected resource.

For example, have each thread gather *ten* pieces of information (or less if it runs out before it's gathered ten) then modify `Foo` to take a length and array - that way, you amortise the cost of the locking, making it much more efficient.

I'd also be very wary of doing:

```
// do quick assignment operation. array[currentCount] = something
```

*outside* the protected area - that's a recipe for disaster since another thread may change `currentCount` from underneath you. That's not a problem if it's a *local* variable since each thread will have its own copy but it's not clear from the code what scope that variable has.

Comment: currentCount is a local variable.

Comment: @user1002479: you can therefore ignore my warning about that.